# OSX UI emacs, git commit/rebase opens empty buffer

Tags: macos, git, emacs

I am using UI emacs on OSX installed through homebrew. I have emacs set to be my git editor. When git opens emacs for a commit message or a rebase merge It opens an empty buffer without any of the git input. Below is my setup:

Emacs shortcut command

```
kev-pc:server kevisazombie$ cat /usr/local/bin/emacs
#!/bin/sh
$(/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@") &
```

Git config

```
kev-pc:server kevisazombie$ cat ~/.gitconfig
[core]
    editor = emacs
    exclusesfile = /Users/kevisazombie/.gitignore_global
    excludesfile = /Users/kevisazombie/.gitignore_global
[color]
    ui = auto
[merge]
        tool = ediff
[mergetool "ediff"]
        cmd = emacs --eval \"(ediff-merge-files-with-ancestor \\\"$LOCAL\\\" \\\"$REMOTE\\\" \\\"$BASE\\\" nil \\\"$MERGED\\\")\"
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps on the [Emacs for OS X website](http://emacsformacosx.com/tips):

Create a script in your `PATH` called "ec" containing

```
#!/bin/sh
which osascript > /dev/null 2>&1 && osascript -e 'tell application "Emacs" to activate'
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient -c "$@"
```

Then use `git config --global core.editor ec`

A simpler version of this is just `git config --global core.editor "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient -c"` but I believe this requires Emacs to be running.

This question should probably be moved to Super User, though.

Comment: I'm not using emacsclient

Comment: Why? Emacsclient's job is simply to ask your existing Emacs instance to open a new buffer for the file you're trying to edit... It does not force you to change anything in your workflow.